# tainted canvas does not allow export, but anonymous cross origin breaks it as well

Tags: javascript, html, video, canvas

I am attempting to get the first frame of a video from an external source, using the following method:

```
function convertVideo(vidSrc) {
    var vid = $('<video src="' + vidSrc + '" preload="metadata" controls style="width: 300px; height: 160px;"></video>')[0];
    vid.load();
    var img;
    vid.onloadedmetadata = function() {
        var cvs = $('<canvas />').attr({ width: 300, height: 160})[0];
        $('.associate-list-container').append(vid);
        try {
            $('.associate-list-container').append(cvs);

            setTimeout(function() {
                cvs.getContext('2d').drawImage(vid, 0, 0, 300, 160);
                img = $('<img/>').attr({src: cvs.toDataURL()})[0]; 
            },100);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }

    }

    return img;
}
```

A few things are happening with this method:

1. When I load the video as it is now, it works, but when I try to export the canvas drawing to an image, it gives me a security error. I have tried the widely known solution of setting the crossOrigin attribute to Anonymous of the video, but that causes the video to completely dissapear. I believe the error linked to the video dissapearing is that there is no valid source.
2. There is a timeout as you can see that delays the drawing of the canvas. For some reason, without that timeout, the canvas stays empty, and the created image is empty. I think the reason for this is because the video isn't loaded yet, which is strange as it should be fully loaded inside the onloadedmetadata function.

Comment: If of different origin cross-origin attribute is required, however, that does not mean the origin server will accept the request. If not, the video will fail loading as you noticed. Either configure the server to allow cross-origin or move the video to your own server. You can also load the video through a proxy which sets proper cross-origin headers.

Comment: If I don't set the cross origin attribute (crossOrigin="Anonymous"), the video fully renders though. Would that not imply that the server is set up to accept the request?

Comment: CORS doesn't apply to presenting data, it will render and show, but you won't be able to *extract* the data using getImageData unless cross-origin requirements are fulfilled.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks for the help!